# How to find all Delve Blogs in the tenant

Tags: powershell, office-365, blog, delve

Recently, Microsoft has announced they are retiring Delve blogs
So we wanted to know how to find all the Delve Blogs in the tenant.

let me know if there is a way to get this information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is find all the site which using the pointpublishingPersonal#0 templates (this is template used for delve personal blogs). below script will take some time as per the number of sites and give you URL, owner and Template. url will be something `https://url/portals/personal/userid`

```
  Connect-SPOService -Url https://<tenanturl>.sharepoint.com
  Get-SPOSite -Limit "All" -IncludePersonalSite $True | ?{$_.Template -eq "POINTPUBLISHINGPERSONAL#0"}
```

Comment: Sarwar - Thank you it helped

Answer (score 0):

https://www.koskila.net/how-to-export-your-delve-blogs-content/ 
The results will include the URL of the site, the page count, last modified, and the email of the blog site owner...